# java.lang.ClassCastException with org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger

Tags: java

I have a cast issue whose generates a `java.lang.ClassCastException` exception:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.MessageFactory;

public class MyLogger extends org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger {

    MyLogger(LoggerContext context, String name, MessageFactory messageFactory) {
        super(context, name, messageFactory);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static MyLogger getLogger(String name) {
        org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger logger_ = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) LogManager
            .getLogger(name);
        return (MyLogger) logger_;
    }
}
```

While this is the same principle as this one:

```
public class test {

    private static class A {

    }

    private static class B extends A {

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a = (A) b;
    }
}
```

Can someone give an explaination?

Comment: Are you sure `LogManager.getLogger(name)` returns an instance of `MyLogger`? Why would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LogManager.getlogger(name)` returns a `org.apache.logging.log4j` object (the interface)

your are trying to store this object in a `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger` object (the implementation), it won't work. Here is an example :

You can store a String in an Object :

```
String s = "foo";
Object o = s;
```

But you can't store an Object in a String :

```
Object o = new Object();
String s = o; // Won't compile
```

Here, the Object is `org.apache.logging.log4j` and the String is `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger`

Here is a solution :

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext; 
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.MessageFactory;

public class MyLogger extends org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger
{
    MyLogger(LoggerContext context, String name, MessageFactory messageFactory) {
        super(context, name, messageFactory);
    }

    public static Logger getLogger(String name) {
        Logger logger_ = LogManager.getLogger(name);
        return logger_;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you I have missed that this function returns the interface and not the object, it's clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

In english please! (En anglais svp!)

In your code:

```
MyLogger extends Logger
```

means that you can cast MyLogger to Logger, but you cannot surely cast Logger to MyLogger.

For example if Dog extends Animal -> you can say that a Dog is an Animal but you cannot say that an Animal is always a Dog !